# textarea's "required" attribute doesn't work even though the value is empty

Tags: html, textarea, required

I created a simple page with list box and text area with conditions that all should be required.

List box are working fine, but textarea box doesn't tell that the field is required to be filled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ratings & Reviews</title>
<body>
<form>

<span>Customer Service*</span>
<span>
    <select name=customer id=aa required>
        <option selected="rate" value="" disabled>rate</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3</option>
        <option value=4>4</option>
        <option value=5>5</option>
    </select>
</span>
<br><br>
<span>Value for money*</span>
<span>
    <select name=money id=aa required>
        <option selected="rate" value="" disabled>rate</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3</option>
        <option value=4>4</option>
        <option value=5>5</option>
    </select>
</span>

<div>
    <textarea name="reviews" rows=11 cols=50 maxlength=250 required>
    </textarea>
</div>

<div id=submit>
    <br>
    <input type=submit name=submit value=submit>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 92):

You have empty space inside text area, remove it:

```
 <textarea name="reviews" rows=11 cols=50 maxlength=250 required ></textarea>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GW3v9/)

Answer (score 15):

The problem is with the spaces between the  tags. You are not supposed to give any spaces in html between these tags, otherwise browser will consider it as the value.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use spaces between opening and closing tags.
**e.g:**

```
<textarea required>**Don't put any space here**</textarea>
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<textarea name="mm" id="mm" rows="5" placeholder="NA if not applicable" required="required"></textarea>
```

Comment: Incorrect. `required` attribute is a boolean value. If it exists, the `textarea` will be required to fill in. Therefore, the behavior of `required` is equal to `required="required"`

Comment: Correct. Quote from W3C's and Whatwg's specs: "If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute’s canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace." https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes
https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes
An attribute value is not required, though.

Comment: Correct and some dynamically created html needs required="required"

Answer (score 3):

And probaly form has `novalidate` attribute. Any form-element validation attributes (like `required` or `regexp`) with form [novalidate attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) will ignore.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem. I left space between opening and closing tag of Textarea as in following code

```
<label><b>Register As:*</b></label>
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control"  
 onchange="toggleInput()" required>
      <option value=''>--Select--</option>
      <option value='Attendee'>Attendee</option>
      <option value='Presenter'>Presenter</option>
</select>

 ...
<textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Explain here what you will present...">  </textarea>
```

and in my javascript I was trying following

```
<script>
   function toggleInput() {  
      if( document.getElementById("category").value=="Attendee"){  
        document.getElementById("description").required = false;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("description").required = true;
      }
   }//End Function
</script>
```

And I could not figure out what was the problem until I landed on this page. It was the space. Thanks @sinisake for the solution. Hope sharing my experience would help someone

Answer (score 2):

Check default value in the textarea. There must be blank spaces which are considered as value.