# How to make a text_area text required using Ruby Form helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following `simple_form_for` that sends an email using **MailForm** (does not store anything on a database)

```
  <div class="small-10 small-offset-1 medium-6 medium-offset-3 large-6 large-offset-3 columns">
    <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :Nombre %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true, :value => 'Administrador', :readonly => true %>
        <%= f.label :Correo_electrónico %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :value => @pass_email, :readonly => true %>
        <%= f.label :Mensaje %>
        <%= f.text_area :message, :as => :text, :required => true, cols: 20, rows: 10 %>
        <div class="hidden">
          <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
        </div>

        </br>
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Enviar', :class => "button [radius round]" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_to 'Volver', manager_admin_menu_path, :method => :get, :class => 'button success [radius round]' %>
  </div>
```

As you can see the `text_area` has a `required => true` but when I test the form it allows to submit empty text in the text_area

How can I validate with rails/ruby that any text was typed in the text_area (basically make the text_area it a required field, I know I can probably do this with javascript but want to learn the correct Ruby/Rails way)

**UPDATE**

My model inherits from `MailForm` and is defined like this

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

end
```

I also want to understand why the **required** option is not behaving as expected

The texarea is being rendered like this

```
<textarea cols="20" id="contact_message" name="contact[message]" required="required" rows="10">
</textarea>
```

Apparently no white spaces but a linebreak is present, does this affect ?

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061436/textarea-required-is-not-working, it may be that a white space is in the text area.

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer I have updated my question with the rendered text area tag

Answer (score 3):

That's the concept of validations in Rails. Validations mean that you make sure a field meets some requirements before saving it to the database, you can validate `presence` which will only submit the form if the the field is not empty, you can validate `uniqueness` which will only submit the form if the field is unique ( does not exist already in the database ), and so on.

So for your concern, you have a Contact model, in your contact.rb file you should add :

```
class Contact <  ActiveRecord::Base 
  validates :message, presence: true // add this line
end
```

Now when you submit the form with empty message field, it will complain and give you an error.

Read here for more into http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: It turns out that the model does not inherit from AcriveRecord but from MailForm `class Contact < MailForm::Base` since this is a form that sends an email